# get user role in resource server from authorization server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I have an authorization server which on the basis of username and password fetches the user details from the DB along with the roles.

Now while accessing the protected resource in the resource server (passing the access_token), I want to authorize the rest call on the basis of role.How do I do that ?
Because, while I am checking the Principal user in resource server, its getting the default [ROLE_USER]

```
//Will @preAuthorize() work here ?
@RequestMapping(value="/pinaki", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Principal principal) {
    return "Hello World";
}
```

Please guide..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK spring-security-oauth2 only supports getting the user details (including roles) for a Authorization Server/Ressource Server that share a common data store (either database or in memory)out of the box.

If you do have a common data store you can use the InMemoryClientDetailsService or JdbcClientDetailsService.

However it should not be too hard to extend this by yourself if in your setup there is no common data store. The key interfaces for this task are **ClientDetailsService** and **ResourceServerTokenServices**.

A ResourceServerTokenServices implementation returns a OAuth2Authentication including roles. So you could call the tokeninfo endpoint from the authorization server here.
Implementing a ClientDetailsService and using that would be more elegant. Here also you would need to call the tokeninfo endpoint.

In XML configuration you can setup the beans to use in the oauth:resource-server tag in the parameters token-services-ref and auth-details-source-ref.
Details on the Java config can be found on page http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html

(My info refers to version 2.0.8 of spring-security-oauth2)